# I am using mysql dumper and i want to disable the database backups *.sql.gz from web

Tags: mysql, security, .htaccess

I am using mysql dumper script from mysqldumper.net.

There is a BasicAuth protection in the script itself which generates it and as a result of it i have to use username and password to login into the mysql dumper panel.

Today i copied the url of one of the database backup files that were saved in its directory and i was able to download the backup file.

This is a cause of concern as I dont want anyone to download the database file directly. I want to download only after entering the username and password set in HTTP BasicAuth.

Here is the code for .htaccess file which is created by mysql dumper

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine off
</IfModule>
AuthName "MySQLDumper"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/home/wwwpsk/public_html/admin/msd/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

and here is the code for .htpasswd

```
dbadmin:{SHA}+xdsf94LDKFDLJIODDK
```

I tried using deny from all but that disables everything i suppose and i dont want to use 
allow from ip etc. as my ISP ip keeps on changing everyday.

So guys whats the solution disable the direct download to all the *.sql.gz files that are there in the directory.

Please help me with it.

Comment: Still no solutions ? I have the same issue.